# TypeScript, Use if statement or question mark to avoid value could be null situation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm currently learning TypeScript.
In the code, inputRef.current could be null, that's why I directly gave question mark. It works. But from the tutorial video, it use an if statement.

Is which way better? or which way is correct?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    inputRef?.current?.focus();
  }, []);
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!inputRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
```

Comment: No difference in this situation. Also `inputRef.current?.focus()` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both should work because optional chaining is like performing multiple if statements to check if the variable or object attribute exists.

That said, this scenario only interacts with inputRef. If there is added logic in the useEffect that affects other variables or elements, then I would opt for option 2, with the return.